# How to properly pass const_iterator& into a function?

Tags: c++, const-iterator

Let's suppose I have a vector of integers and want to process it in an odd recursive manner (this situation might sound strange without a context, but still).

I want to use const_iterators to track current position. Here is `odd_recursive_stuff()` prototype:

```
// Note: changing "std::vector<int>::const_iterator& it_cur"
// into "std::vector<int>::const_iterator it_cur" will change
// the side effects!
void odd_recursive_stuff (std::vector<int>::const_iterator&  it_cur, 
                          std::vector<int>::const_iterator   it_end);
```

Firstly I tried to call it this way:

```
void process_vec (const std::vector<int> &vec) {
  odd_recursive_stuff (std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
}
```

Luckily, It doesn't compile (in clang 8.0.0 for example):

```
Error: no matching function for call to 'recursive_odd_stuff'
Candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument!
```

Because `std::begin()` returns r-value, so  I have to call it another way that works:

```
void process_vec (const std::vector<int> &vec) {
   std::vector<int>::const_iterator it_beg = std::begin (vec);
   recursive_odd_stuff (it_beg, std::end(vec));
}
```

Now I'm wondering **if it is possible to call the base of `recursive_odd_stuff()` with a single line without local_variable `it_beg`**?

It seems that It is impossible to write another version of `begin()` which returns l-value, because "the return value of a function is an l-value if and only if it is a reference (C++03). (5.2.2 [expr.call] / 10)". So the only way is to call it with two lines?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to take the `const_iterator` in by reference?

Comment: Is it a problem? You can always wrap it in another function. Perhaps something like `recursive_odd_stuff` and `recursive_odd_stuff_impl`? And no, begin cannot return a l-value by value(not a reference), because l-values, roughly speaking, must be named.

Comment: Instead of taking a reference to a mutable const_iterator, consider returning the current position instead of mutating the caller's non-temporary argument.

Comment: @templatetypedef, originally I faced it in a sort of tree traversal problem, where I had to check some property of tree which depends on an external vector, so I had to use iterator to that vector during recursive traversing to know if It changed in subtree.

Comment: @Quimby It's a solution, but It looks similar to making a local variable `it_beg`.

Comment: The benefit of Quimby's solution is it puts the burden on the implementation side, rather than on the caller's side.  (For a small project, probably doesn't matter.  But at scale, always helps to be mindful of the burden imposed on the caller rather than the callee.)

Comment: @Eljay your returning-iterator solution works fine, but does it mean that passing a reference to an iterator should be avoided?

Comment: No, sometimes passing a reference to an iterator (or a reference to any kind of object) is the right thing to do.  Depends on what is trying to be achieved, and the contract for the function.  I prefer to make as much as possible follow value semantics, but that is by no means common "best practice" in the industry for C++, it has its fans, and those who dislike it.

Comment: Personally I also follow the rule “passing by reference is usually better”, but asked you just to clarify if there is a special convention about iterators. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there's a way to make it a one-liner, but I don't recommend it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

void odd_recursive_stuff (std::vector<int>::const_iterator&  it_cur, 
                          std::vector<int>::const_iterator   it_end){}

void process_vec (const std::vector<int> &vec) {
  odd_recursive_stuff ([it=std::begin(vec)]()mutable{return std::ref(it);}(), std::end(vec));
}
```

I think that your n-th recursive call changes the reference which is then used by the n-1th caller to do something. In this case, I would recommend splitting the code into two functions:

```
odd_recursive_stuff(IT begin, IT end){
    odd_recursive_stuff_impl(begin, end);
}
odd_recursive_stuff_impl(IT& begin, IT& end){
    ....
}
```

This exposes a public interface that just requires iterators. Later when you change the algorithm in a way that does not require the reference, or it will require `end` to be a reference too, then you don't have to change all calls.

The first solution might expand into something akin to this:

```
void process_vec (const std::vector<int> &vec) {
    using IT = std::vector<int>::const_iterator;
    struct _lambda_type{
            _lambda_type(const IT& it):_it(it){}

            //By default lambda's () is const method, hence the mutable qualifier.
            std::reference_wrapper<IT> operator()()/*Not const*/{
                return std::ref(_it);
            }
        private:
            IT _it;
    };
    //Previous lines...
    {//The line with the call.
        //Lambda is created before the call and lives until the expression is fully evaluated.
        _lambda_type lambda{std::begin(vec)};
        odd_recursive_stuff (lambda(), std::end(vec));
    }//Here's the lambda destroyed. So the call is perfectly safe.
    //The rest...
}
```

The lambda's `operator()` returns a reference to a local variable, but it's local to the lambda object, not the `operator()` itself. Because the lambda object lives until the end of the expression(`;`) the call is safe. Just note that I used `std::ref` as a quick way to return a reference without the need to mention the return type explicitly. `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is then implicitly convertible to `T&`.

`return it;` would return by value and `[it=std::begin(vec)]()mutable ->decltype(it)&{...};` is not possible either. `->decltype(std::begin(vec))&{` works but it's wordy. Another alternatives are to write the iterator's type explicitly or use a `using` but that's even worse.

Comment: Wow, it’s possible even with one line. Thanks! But isn’t ‘it’ a local variable inside lambda? So you return a ref to a local variable??

Comment: @gimme_danger In a sense, yes. I expanded the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Overloading!

Have a version that accepts only rvalues:

```
void odd_recursive_stuff (std::vector<int>::const_iterator&& it_cur, 
                          std::vector<int>::const_iterator   it_end);
```

…and a version that accepts lvalue-references (and does the extra line for you):

```
void odd_recursive_stuff (const std::vector<int>::const_iterator& it_cur, 
                                std::vector<int>::const_iterator  it_end)
{
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it_copy(it_cur);
    odd_recursive_stuff(std::move(it_copy), it_end);
}
```

This is the same principle upon which move semantics are based, because copy- and move-constructors are selected in the same way.

But you might consider dropping this whole thing, and just returning the new value of `it` instead:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator
odd_recursive_stuff(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it_cur, 
                    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it_end);
```

You are then free to discard it at will.

Nobody really expects an iterator to be taken by reference.